# How to remove row action "Edit with Visual Composer" in the post list table?

Tags: plugins, row-actions

- I am using Visual Composer plugin.
- I've found a snippet to remove row actions in post list table in word press.

  ```
  add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'remove_row_actions', 10, 1 );

  function remove_row_actions( $actions )
  {
      if( get_post_type() === 'my_cpt' )
          unset( $actions['view'] );
      return $actions;
  }
  ```
- but I could not found the row action name for the `Edit with Visual Composer`
- I want to remove or edit the link into the Row Action "".

Have a look on screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general change the filter priority in your code snippet so it runs after the plugin has modified the row action, e.g. `99` or later and check out the `$actions` with e.g.

```
print_r( $actions );
```

on your test install to find the key or search the plugin code for `page_row_actions`.

In some cases one should be able to remove the `page_row_actions` filter callback with `remove_filter()`, but some plugins make it harder.

ps: I think you're looking for the `edit_vc` row action key.

Comment: Thanks @birgire, It works by changing the priority to `99` and then `unset($actions['edit_vc'])`

Comment: you're welcome, glad to hear it worked @Esar-ul-haqQasmi